# How to listen to specific click events but suppress others?

Tags: javascript

My web application contains an HTML table where each row links to a specific URL:

```
<table>
  <tr data-url="https://www.google.com">
    <td>Google</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-url="https://www.yahoo.com">
    <td>Yahoo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the Javascript to make it work:

```
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tr[data-url]');

rows.forEach(row => {
  row.addEventListener('click', function() {
    handleClick(row);
  });
});

function handleClick(row) {
  const url = row.dataset.url;
  window.document.location = url;
}
```

This code works great.

Now my client wants me to add checkboxes to those table cells. (I won't go into detail why.)

How can I suppress the re-direct when a checkbox gets selected?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Apply the event to the `td` instead of the `tr` or eventually use a span inside with an event

Comment: can't you add another td with the checkbox only and the data-url to your other td with the `google` or `Yahoo` text?

Comment: Good point but I have about a dozen `td` elements, so I don't want to have to add it to each one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the event's target is not a checkbox.

```js
rows.forEach(row => {
  row.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('input[type=checkbox]')) handleClick(row);
  });
});
```

Comment: You may also want to put the checkbox in a slightly larger div or something to give it some space, i.e. if the user clicks one pixel outside the checkbox they probably just missed, and don't want to get thrust off to a new page...